# Isolated points in $B(S)$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $B(S)$ be the set of all bounded real-valued functions on $S$ where $S$ is any non-empty set. Let the metric be the metric of uniform convergence. Does $B(S)$ have any isolated points if $S$ is finite?

Comment: "...all bounded... **real?** ...functions..."?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes Im sorry, fixed

Comment: But...what is $\,S\,$ ? A subset of the reals, an arbitrary metric space...?

Comment: @Don any non-empty set

Comment: This space is usually denoted $R^n$ where $n$ is the cardinality of your finite set $S$. Now, ask yourself when such a space has isolated points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $S=\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n\}$. Let

$$\varphi:B(S)\to\Bbb R^n:f\mapsto\langle f(s_1),f(s_2),\ldots,f(s_n)\rangle\;.$$

Prove that $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism. Does $\Bbb R^n$ have any isolated points?